# Limit actions per user based on IP, sessions, cookies, or what? How do newspaper websites limit number of articles read?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, session-cookies, rate-limiting

I am currently working on a website where I want to limit the number of actions a user can do, where the user may not be logged in. I want to take some reasonable steps to be able to track individual users for this purpose, even though I know that a lot of things can be spoofed or worked around, I don't think that many people would be motivated to take that route with my specific application.

I am pretty impressed by what newspaper websites like NYTimes.com. They sometimes seem to stop me even when I'm in private browser mode and have deleted my cookies. Sometimes I seem to be able to get around it, but in the case of my website users wouldn't be motivated to attempt a workaround. Something like nytimes.com, where it is resilient against a simple case of a browser not saving cookies or, cookies having been deleted, or the browser being in private mode, would be great.

I am working in Rails but I am more interested conceptually in the approach than the specific implementation. Do they use IPs, cookies, sessions, some sort of unique computer ID, or some combination?

I am having trouble coming up with the correct google search to look this up. Searches for "rate limiting" only yield articles about limiting HTTP requests, searches for "event tracking" only talk about logging events but not necessarily the approach to using cookies, sessions, IPs, or whatever else in order to accurately detect unique users, even when they haven't logged in.

Comment: Try searching for "anonymous users rails" it yields some results, but most are old and outdated, at least from out of the box solutions. If you are building your own, it's probably a mix of everything you said, just know the limits (or test NYTimes ones: public libraries, computers in the same network, different browsers in the same computer, etc.)

Comment: Thanks @Leito. From the little I've been able to find, seems like there's no silver bullet for this feature, a messy combination of cookies and IP logging no matter what you do. I wish I could find more specific advice.